# Active Directory Domain Controller Not Appearing in Network Folder

Tags: networking, samba, smb, samba4

I'm having issues with my Active Directory domain controller, where my server does not show up on Network or My Network Places. I am running Samba 4.1.6-Ubuntu on Ubuntu Server 14.04.3.

This issue occurred since the computer went from a workgroup to a domain. If I type in smb://ubuntu-server or smb://192.168.1.100 (the NetBIOS name and IP address of the server), I am able to access the server just fine.

Also, I am able to use "net lookup ubuntu-server" to get an IP address from a NetBIOS name, and "nmblookup -A 192.168.1.100" to find the NetBIOS name from the IP address.

I do have the results of a few commands that may have some clues:

```
andy@ubuntu-server:~$ nmblookup -A 192.168.1.100
Looking up status of 192.168.1.100
        UBUNTU-SERVER   <00> -         M <ACTIVE> 
        UBUNTU-SERVER   <03> -         M <ACTIVE> 
        UBUNTU-SERVER   <20> -         M <ACTIVE> 
        FAMILY          <1b> -         M <ACTIVE> 
        FAMILY          <1c> - <GROUP> M <ACTIVE> 
        FAMILY          <00> - <GROUP> M <ACTIVE> 
        __SAMBA__       <00> - <GROUP> M <ACTIVE> <PERMANENT> 
        __SAMBA__       <20> - <GROUP> M <ACTIVE> <PERMANENT> 

        MAC Address = 00-00-00-00-00-00

andy@ubuntu-server:~$ smbclient -L localhost -Uadministrator
Enter administrator's password:
Domain=[FAMILY] OS=[Unix] Server=[Samba 4.1.6-Ubuntu]

        Sharename       Type      Comment
        ---------       ----      -------
        print$          Disk      Printer Drivers
        Andy            Disk      
        netlogon        Disk      
        sysvol          Disk      
        Users           Disk      
        IPC$            IPC       IPC Service (ubuntu-server server (Samba, Ubuntu))
        MFCJ835DW       Printer   MFCJ835DW
        HP_Officejet_4630_series Printer   HP Officejet 4630 series 
Domain=[FAMILY] OS=[Unix] Server=[Samba 4.1.6-Ubuntu]

        Server               Comment
        ---------            -------

        Workgroup            Master
        ---------            -------
        WORKGROUP            UBUNTU-SERVER
```

I notice that the AD DC is not becoming the local master browser when it is the only domain computer on the network. I did not find a #1d entry entitled FAMILY or an _ _ MSBROWSE _ _ entry through nmblookup in the one computer case. Also, I find that in the smbclient command above, UBUNTU-SERVER lists itself under the workgroup WORKGROUP.

Running testparm seems to work fine, but here is my /etc/samba/smb.conf file:

```
#
# Sample configuration file for the Samba suite for Debian GNU/Linux.
#
#
# This is the main Samba configuration file. You should read the
# smb.conf(5) manual page in order to understand the options listed
# here. Samba has a huge number of configurable options most of which 
# are not shown in this example
#
# Some options that are often worth tuning have been included as
# commented-out examples in this file.
#  - When such options are commented with ";", the proposed setting
#    differs from the default Samba behaviour
#  - When commented with "#", the proposed setting is the default
#    behaviour of Samba but the option is considered important
#    enough to be mentioned here
#
# NOTE: Whenever you modify this file you should run the command
# "testparm" to check that you have not made any basic syntactic 
# errors. 

#======================= Global Settings =======================

[global]

## Browsing/Identification ###

# Change this to the workgroup/NT-domain name your Samba server will part of
        workgroup = FAMILY
;       netbios name = ubuntu-server

# server string is the equivalent of the NT Description field
        server string = %h server (Samba, Ubuntu)

# Windows Internet Name Serving Support Section:
# WINS Support - Tells the NMBD component of Samba to enable its WINS Server
#   wins support = no

# WINS Server - Tells the NMBD components of Samba to be a WINS Client
# Note: Samba can be either a WINS Server, or a WINS Client, but NOT both
;   wins server = w.x.y.z

# This will prevent nmbd to search for NetBIOS names through DNS.
        dns proxy = no

        name resolve order = lmhosts wins bcast host

# Andy's entry to make sure that the AD DC becomes the local master
# browser.

        domain master = yes
        preferred master = yes
        os level = 65

#### Networking ####

# The specific set of interfaces / networks to bind to
# This can be either the interface name or an IP address/netmask;
# interface names are normally preferred
;   interfaces = 127.0.0.0/8 eth0

# Only bind to the named interfaces and/or networks; you must use the
# 'interfaces' option above to use this.
# It is recommended that you enable this feature if your Samba machine is
# not protected by a firewall or is a firewall itself.  However, this
# option cannot handle dynamic or non-broadcast interfaces correctly.
;   bind interfaces only = yes



#### Debugging/Accounting ####

# This tells Samba to use a separate log file for each machine
# that connects
        log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m

# Cap the size of the individual log files (in KiB).
        max log size = 1000

# If you want Samba to only log through syslog then set the following
# parameter to 'yes'.
#   syslog only = no

# We want Samba to log a minimum amount of information to syslog. Everything
# should go to /var/log/samba/log.{smbd,nmbd} instead. If you want to log
# through syslog you should set the following parameter to something higher.
        syslog = 0

# Do something sensible when Samba crashes: mail the admin a backtrace
        panic action = /usr/share/samba/panic-action %d


####### Authentication #######

# Server role. Defines in which mode Samba will operate. Possible
# values are "standalone server", "member server", "classic primary
# domain controller", "classic backup domain controller", "active
# directory domain controller". 
#
# Most people will want "standalone sever" or "member server".
# Running as "active directory domain controller" will require first
# running "samba-tool domain provision" to wipe databases and create a
# new domain.
        server role = active directory domain controller
        realm = family.local
        dns forwarder = 192.168.1.1
        idmap_ldb:use rfc2307 = yes

# If you are using encrypted passwords, Samba will need to know what
# password database type you are using.  
;       passdb backend = tdbsam

        obey pam restrictions = yes

# This boolean parameter controls whether Samba attempts to sync the Unix
# password with the SMB password when the encrypted SMB password in the
# passdb is changed.
        unix password sync = yes

# For Unix password sync to work on a Debian GNU/Linux system, the following
# parameters must be set (thanks to Ian Kahan <<kahan@informatik.tu-muenchen.de> for
# sending the correct chat script for the passwd program in Debian Sarge).
        passwd program = /usr/bin/passwd %u
        passwd chat = *Enter\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *Retype\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *password\supdated\ssuccessfully* .

# This boolean controls whether PAM will be used for password changes
# when requested by an SMB client instead of the program listed in
# 'passwd program'. The default is 'no'.
        pam password change = yes

# This option controls how unsuccessful authentication attempts are mapped
# to anonymous connections
        map to guest = bad user

########## Domains ###########

#
# The following settings only takes effect if 'server role = primary
# classic domain controller', 'server role = backup domain controller'
# or 'domain logons' is set 
#

# It specifies the location of the user's
# profile directory from the client point of view) The following
# required a [profiles] share to be setup on the samba server (see
# below)
;   logon path = \\%N\profiles\%U
# Another common choice is storing the profile in the user's home directory
# (this is Samba's default)
#   logon path = \\%N\%U\profile

# The following setting only takes effect if 'domain logons' is set
# It specifies the location of a user's home directory (from the client
# point of view)
;   logon drive = H:
#   logon home = \\%N\%U

# The following setting only takes effect if 'domain logons' is set
# It specifies the script to run during logon. The script must be stored
# in the [netlogon] share
# NOTE: Must be store in 'DOS' file format convention
;   logon script = logon.cmd

# This allows Unix users to be created on the domain controller via the SAMR
# RPC pipe.  The example command creates a user account with a disabled Unix
# password; please adapt to your needs
; add user script = /usr/sbin/adduser --quiet --disabled-password --gecos "" %u

# This allows machine accounts to be created on the domain controller via the 
# SAMR RPC pipe.  
# The following assumes a "machines" group exists on the system
; add machine script  = /usr/sbin/useradd -g machines -c "%u machine account" -d /var/lib/samba -s /bin/false %u

# This allows Unix groups to be created on the domain controller via the SAMR
# RPC pipe.  
; add group script = /usr/sbin/addgroup --force-badname %g

############ Misc ############

# Using the following line enables you to customise your configuration
# on a per machine basis. The %m gets replaced with the netbios name
# of the machine that is connecting
;   include = /home/samba/etc/smb.conf.%m

# Some defaults for winbind (make sure you're not using the ranges
# for something else.)
;   idmap uid = 10000-20000
;   idmap gid = 10000-20000
;   template shell = /bin/bash

# Setup usershare options to enable non-root users to share folders
# with the net usershare command.

# Maximum number of usershare. 0 (default) means that usershare is disabled.
;       usershare max shares = 100

# Allow users who've been granted usershare privileges to create
# public shares, not just authenticated ones
        usershare allow guests = yes
        username map = /etc/samba/smbusers

#======================= Share Definitions =======================

# Un-comment the following (and tweak the other settings below to suit)
# to enable the default home directory shares. This will share each
# user's home directory as \\server\username
;[homes]
;   comment = Home Directories
;   browseable = no

# By default, the home directories are exported read-only. Change the
# next parameter to 'no' if you want to be able to write to them.
;   read only = yes

# File creation mask is set to 0700 for security reasons. If you want to
# create files with group=rw permissions, set next parameter to 0775.
;   create mask = 0700

# Directory creation mask is set to 0700 for security reasons. If you want to
# create dirs. with group=rw permissions, set next parameter to 0775.
;   directory mask = 0700

# By default, \\server\username shares can be connected to by anyone
# with access to the samba server.
# Un-comment the following parameter to make sure that only "username"
# can connect to \\server\username
# This might need tweaking when using external authentication schemes
;   valid users = %S

# Un-comment the following and create the netlogon directory for Domain Logons
# (you need to configure Samba to act as a domain controller too.)
;[netlogon]
;   comment = Network Logon Service
;   path = /home/samba/netlogon
;   guest ok = yes
;   read only = yes

# Un-comment the following and create the profiles directory to store
# users profiles (see the "logon path" option above)
# (you need to configure Samba to act as a domain controller too.)
# The path below should be writable by all users so that their
# profile directory may be created the first time they log on
;[profiles]
;   comment = Users profiles
;   path = /home/samba/profiles
;   guest ok = no
;   browseable = no
;   create mask = 0600
;   directory mask = 0700

[printers]
        comment = All Printers
        browseable = no
        path = /var/spool/samba
        printable = yes
;       guest ok = no
;       read only = yes
        create mask = 0700

# Windows clients look for this share name as a source of downloadable
# printer drivers
[print$]
        comment = Printer Drivers
        path = /var/lib/samba/printers
;       browseable = yes
;       read only = yes
;       guest ok = no
# Uncomment to allow remote administration of Windows print drivers.
# You may need to replace 'lpadmin' with the name of the group your
# admin users are members of.
# Please note that you also need to set appropriate Unix permissions
# to the drivers directory for these users to have write rights in it
;   write list = root, @lpadmin

[Andy]
        path = /home/andy
;       available = yes
;       browseable = yes
;       public = no
        writable = yes

[netlogon]
        path = /var/lib/samba/sysvol/family.local/scripts
        read only = no

[sysvol]
        path = /var/lib/samba/sysvol
        read only = no
```

I was wondering how I would make my domain controller appear again in the Network folder.

If any other system info or test results are needed, please let me know.